# Specific Font in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

I would like to make a presentation using a font style like this one: http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/slides/fpottier-2008-06-pittsburgh.pdf

---

Screenshot:

[image]

---

Does anyone know which font is this?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: That font is some form of *Tekton* bold.

Comment: In 40 minutes the question became closed, by OP haven't obtained an answer. The source, given as a source of an answer, couldn't help me in identifying a font.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: See [Informal Math Fonts from MicroPress](http://www.micropress-inc.com/samples/ifonts.htm) for a reference of the font used. From there one could attempt to download the font once the name - Informal Math - has been identified. As mentioned in the linked post, "Informal Math is a set of fonts loosely based on the Adobe's Tekton (TM) family with all TeX mathematical symbols".

Comment: @Werner Thank you! Now I know the name of a font. I assume that in not Tekton bold, as suggested in comments. I am rather new here and I am still learning SX's customaries. In particular, the policy of closing questions sometimes remains for me mysterious.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: The linked/source [duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764) stems from [a discussion on Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2330/5764) over a year ago. Mostly questions regarding specific fonts in documents are considered off-topic here. However, it was informally decided that a catch-all "duplicate" be generated for the purpose of keeping things TeX-related. Sure, the longer you're here, the more history you accumulate. Question closing is a community-driven initiative, yet the addiction to contribution (through rep or badges) is mysterious at times.